# Extract table from a site within local domain

Tags: javascript

We have a program for keeping track of entrances and exits to our office and want to be able to extract the data from the web interface to put into a separate database. Is this something that can be accomplished with JavaScript?

Comment: With JavaScript like node.js...yes.

Comment: I'm pretty wet behind the ears with JavaScript. Is Node.js pretty easy to figure out for a n00b?

Comment: It's easy but probably not something you want to start learning JavaScript with.

Answer (score 1):

Try using TableTools to accomplish this with JavaScript: http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/